# Is there a connotative difference between "leniency" and "lenity"?

Tags: differences

Being no native speaker, I cannot discern the difference between those two. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: NNS can  check dictionaries, though. ***lenity*** - 
n.
The condition or quality of being lenient; leniency. https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lenity - Of interest: ***leniency*** is the more commonly used between the two: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lenity%2C+leniency+&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clenity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleniency%3B%2Cc0

Comment: What dictionaries have you consulted?

Comment: The main difference is that most people have an idea of what "leniency" means.  They haven''t a clue about "lenity".

Answer (score 1):

The word *lenity* in current usage is usually limited to legal contexts, especially in discussions of the so-called [*Rule of Lenity*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_lenity), which stipulates that any ambiguity or discrepancy in the law is to be interpreted in the defendant's favor. The word is likely unfamiliar outside of legal circles.

*Leniency*, however, is a general term far better known.